# jQuery Datatables filtering a column when the columns content is html

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a column in a dataTable that I want to filter. I can filter by columns which are defined like this:

```
"columns": [
    { 
        "data": function (data) {
             return data['columnToFilter'];
        }
    },
];
```

But, I can't find a way to filter columns which are more than the original value, such as this one:

```
"columns": [
    { 
        "data": function (data) {
            return '<h1>' + data['columnToFilter'] + '</h1>';
         }          
    }
];
```

How can I tell dataTables what raw the value (without the html) of the second column is?

Here is my code that does the filtering:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        // tabLocation can only be filtered if the value is returned without additional html
        var tabLocation = data[0];
        if ($("#myFilter").hasClass("down")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if (tabLocation == 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
);

$.fn.toggleText = function(t1, t2){
    if (this.text() == t1) this.text(t2);
    else                   this.text(t1);
    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used was this:

```
"columns": [
    { 
        "data": function (data) {
            return data['columnToFilter'];
        },
        "render": {
            "display": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                return '<h1>' + data['columnToFilter'] + '</h1>';
            },
        },
        "bSortable": false,
    },
];
```